# UFT detects chrome as winobj after UFT opens the browser

Tags: google-chrome-extension, hp-uft, uft14, uft-api

UFT launches Chrome but it detects it as winobject. If I open it manually it sees chrome as browser. How can I fix this?

Comment: Flagged as uft14? Don't try to use anything lower than 14.53+patches. And Chrome and Edge support, however, requires UFT15+. Don´t try to use current browsers with UFT 14.x, it will seem to work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the chrome extension is enabled.

Go to: chrome://extensions/

Validate it's enabled:

[image: UFTChromeExtension]

Sometimes the extension is installed but is not enabled by default.

If that doesn't work can you confirm how you're launching chrome with UFT?

A solid way is: `systemutil.run "chrome", url'`

Comment: UFT extension is enabled, UFT launches chrome from the record and run settings screen, not from a line of code.

Comment: @JaimeGaray Then i suggest you try that line of code :-)  -  Chrome can exist in multiple installation locations on a single machine and have different profiles. You might be launching the "wrong" chrome on your box. Look at how you launch chrome manually, you might be running a file path or execution arguments you're not aware of - corporate policies may be in affect without you realising.... If you migrate this coded approach of test/environment data management you're in much greater control of the execution.

Comment: I did that. The browser opens now, however now the browser is identified as browser instead as a web broswer. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: Hi Jamie,  probably best to edit your question and add some more detail.  Probably show a picture of your issue and what the object spy identifies when you point it at an element.

Comment: Maybe old, but: UFT detecting a Browser testobject as opposed to a WebBrowser testobject is correct because the testobject indeed is named "Browser", not "WebBrowser". There is no "WebBrowser" testobject in UFT.